# .Net Filestream - handle vs path

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Newbie question...

I am reviewing the [.Net Filestream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for use in a personal project which involves creating files and saving them. I have always simply used the constructor that passes in a path and file mode.  Could someone explain how the constructor that takes in a SafeFileHandler and FileAccess class is different?  When might I use a handler instead of a path?

I use both VB.Net and C# - no preference here if you give examples.

Comment: I take issue with the down vote.  Research was done before posting.  People just "use" them  and don't explain it - it's as if we are supposed to know already.  Sometimes basic questions are like that.

Comment: You should try to not take issue, otherwise you 'll have a very hard time being on the internet. Of course the unexplained downvote is not nice, but why care about an action that isn't nice and doesn't really affect you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor exists to facilitate the scenario where a handle to the file has already been opened by a native function such as [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using platform invoke.

You can see this by the fact that `SafeHandle` is declared (further down) inside the namespace `Microsoft.Win32`, which clearly means that it is something that only applies in scenarios where you are working with the Win32 API.

Furthermore, the documentation for the [`Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace states that

> The `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles` namespace contains classes that are
>   abstract derivations of safe handle classes that provide common
>   functionality supporting file and operating system handles.
>
> These classes are derived from the
>   `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle` and
>   `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle` classes.

which clearly refers specifically to interop with native code.